# Initramfs-tools script for mounting compressed folders on tmpfs

Tags: initramfs, initrd

I'm trying to create a small rescue partition (~800MB spare space after all other system and storage partitions) for a laptop with specialized hardware that requires special kernel and kernel modules such that stock rescue tools such as Clonezilla Live and GParted Live don't work very well. The partition is too small to include the modules and software needed for what I'd like to build, so the bulk of the system needs to be compressed and loaded into RAM at runtime. Additionally, I prefer to have the system fully extracted instead of relying on `squashfs`, and I would like the ability to save changes made to the system as much as the partition allows. Using Ubuntu 20.04 as the base system, I devised the following scheme for this purpose:

1. After building the initial system in `chroot`, create and empty folder `/ram` as the mount point for the `tmpfs` to house decompressed system and user files at runtime, move  all system and user file folders (`home`,`usr`,`var`,`opt`,`etc`, *etc.*) into `/ram` and replace each with a symbolic link to `/ram/$dir`. Compress `/ram` as`/ram.tar.gz` and leave the special mount points (`dev`, `sys` ,`run` ,`tmp`, and `proc`) as well as `boot` alone on `rootfs`. Delete `/ram/*` and write the `rootfs` onto the partition.
2. At boot, after kernel and `initrd` are loaded, premount `rootfs`, mount `tmpfs` on `/ram`, then extract the content of `/ram.tar.gz` into `/ram`. This has to happen before `rootfs` replaces `initramfs` as root since otherwise `rootfs` can't access the utilities needed to mount `/ram` and extract from the compressed archive.
3. Mount `rootfs` and proceed with boot.
4. At shutdown, back up `/ram.tar.gz` as `/ram.tar.gz.bak` then compress the modified `/ram` into `/ram.tar.gz`. This can be achieved using `systemd`.

Obviously things can go wrong in step 4 and therefore step 2 needs to include the integrity of `/ram.tar.gz` and load the backup if that fails, but this should be just a few additional commands to include in the `initramfs-tools` script and beyond the scope of my question, which is:

Without altering `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/init`, how do I create a script in `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts` to accomplish step 2? The commands should be easy enough as

```
mount -t tmpfs -o $OPTIONS none /ram
tar xvzf ram.tar.gz
```

But I'm a bit at loss as to which folder to include the script (init? local? top? bottom? premount?) and how to work with the `PREREQ` header in the script itself.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be pretty straightforward. Create:

```
/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-bottom/ramfiles
```

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e

PREREQ=""

prereqs()
{
        echo "${PREREQ}"
}

case "${1}" in
        prereqs)
                prereqs
                exit 0
                ;;
esac

mount -t tmpfs -o size=100% none ${rootmnt}/ram
tar xvzf ${rootmnt}/ram.tar.gz -C ${rootmnt}
```

then

```bsh
sudo chmod +x /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-bottom/ramfiles
sudo update-initramfs -u
```